# Can someone simplify this? It's a closed form for the approximation of $(\ln(2))!.$

Tags: factorial, gamma-function

I need help simplifying this

> ## $$\ln\left(2\right)e^{\left(\ln2-\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln\left(\ln\left(2\right)\right)-\ln2+\frac{\ln\left(2\pi\right)}{2}+2\left(e^{\left(\frac{11}{3}-\frac{2e}{3}+\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{(8\pi)}{3}\right)}\pi^{(1+e)}\cos^{2}(e\pi)\right)}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi\ln\left(2\right)}{2}}\ln\left(2\right)^{\ln\left(2\right)}\exp(2\sqrt[3\pi]{e^{\pi\left(11-2e-8\pi\right)+3}}\pi^{1+e}\cos^{2}\pi e)$$

Will this do the trick?